# Auto-populate the description column through trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I would like to auto-populate the description column through trigger but I'm stuck in the inserting part, here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "INSERT_MESSAGE" AFTER INSERT, UPDATE ON "A"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT "SEQ_A".NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.MESSAGE FROM DUAL
END;
/
```

There is a table "A" which has a column "MESSAGE", and the message will be generated into that column with a specific format: "Hi how are you?" How can I generate this text into that column when the trigger is activated? Thank you.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: thanks for remind :) @marc_s

Comment: ? So is it MySQL, or Oracle? Please take @marc_s question seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Logically you cannot change something after it's happened and there are a few syntax issues with your code. Try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "INSERT_MESSAGE" before INSERT or UPDATE ON "A" 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
SELECT “SEQ_A”.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.MESSAGE FROM DUAL ;
END;
```

Comment: As a further refactoring we could remove all of the double-quotes and the redundant `select from dual`.